# Find Specific IP Address in a String with PHP preg_match()

Tags: php, regex

My PHP code needs to decide whether or not a specific IP address is in the string `$ipaddress`:

```
preg_match("[1][4]\.[1][0][8]\.[2][4][1]\.[6][9]", $ipaddress )
```

This doesn't work for some reason. Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: `[1][4]\.[1][0][8]\.[2][4][1]\.[6][9]` is better written `14\.108\.241\.69`

Comment: how about `"14\.108\.241\.69"` or just `strstr()`???

Comment: You forgot delimiters: `'~14\.108\.241\.69~'`. Why not use `strpos` since it is a literal?

Comment: You're not strict enough at the start `114` and `214` would also match up. Use `^` for starting anchor, or `\D14\.104\.241\.69`. The character classes are unneeded.

Comment: perl: `/(?<!\d)\Q14.108.241.69\E(?!\d)/`. With quotemeta (`\Q`, `\E`), no need to escape backslashes. With the negative lookarounds, it ensures that only that IP will be caught. If this is a case where the variable ONLY contains an IP, `if ($ipaddress eq '14.108.241.69'){...}`

Answer (score 3):

`[1]` and `1` is the same thing, there is no point in creating groups of one element. You can look straight for `14\.108\.241\.69`.

What is missing for this to work are the delimiters. When using Perl regular expressions the pattern must be enclosed by delimiters, typically `/`, `#` or `~`.

```
preg_match('/14\.108\.241\.69/', $ipaddress)
preg_match('~14\.108\.241\.69~', $ipaddress)
preg_match('#14\.108\.241\.69#', $ipaddress)
```

Are all valid uses of `preg_match()`.

Because you are looking for a simple piece of string, you don't really need `preg_match()`, a simple `strstr($ipaddress, '14.108.241.69') !== FALSE` will do the job just as well and faster.